# Failed to install openjdk in Debian Stretch

Tags: debian, apt, docker, openjdk

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-stretch

RUN echo "deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install \
    --no-install-recommends -qq -y \
    apt-utils \
    poppler-utils \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libfontconfig-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libopenjp2-7-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    pdftk \
    ghostscript \
    autoconf \
    automake \
    libtool \
    autoconf-archive \
    pkg-config \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libtiff5-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    imagemagick \
    wget \
    procps \
    curl \
    locales \
    libicu-dev \
    libpango1.0-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    g++ \
    make

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1 && apt install -y openjdk-8-jdk


ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-l" ]
```

But it started to fail during installation of openjdk-8:

```
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
The command '/bin/sh -c mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1 && apt install -y openjdk-8-jdk' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I've got it to work adding stretch-backports to sources list, but I don't know why it works. As far as I know, backports are disabled by default:

```
RUN echo "deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

I would like to know why it starts to break only now and why adding stretch-backports or `http://security.debian.org/debian-security oldoldstable/updates main` to sources make it works.

Comment: When you started the installation, your sources.list contained only the "stable" repos of stretch, and openjdk-8-jdk installation failed because it's not available in those. It is available in [backport repos](https://backports.debian.org/), so after adding them you were able to install it. I don't quite understand what exactly you are asking. Also "starts to break only now" is unclear - has this exact same process worked before without adding backports?

Comment: Why oldoldstable works is because the releases changed status. When Buster was current, it was the "stable" release and Stretch was the "oldstable". Release of Bullsaye relegated Buster to "oldstable" status, and pushed Stretch to "oldoldstable".

Comment: I have to clarify: I didn't actually dig into Stretch repos to see where exactly openjdk-8-jdk is, that's just an assumption based on how apt usually works. The status change of Stretch is a different thing, that's how the status of Debian releases changes over time. In general backports are indeed disabled by default i.e. commented out in sources.list, and the recommendation is to uncomment then only if a installation of a specific package requires it, after which they should be commented out again.

Comment: I mean, the build from that docker image break for the first time this week, despite it has been up for months. Ok, openjdk is available in backport repos, but isn't those disable by default? In other words, shouldn't I specify that I want to install something from backport?

Comment: I'm sorry but I know nothing about docker yet... You are absolutely correct, as I said above the backports are disabled by default etc. Why it now failed; I can only guess that Debian changed something. I run into similar issue a while back, some installation failed. If I remember it right some change wasn't reflected in wherever apt update gets the list until a few days later so later, a human error that was corrected immediately when they learned about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `openjdk-8-jdk` is available on the repos used by Docker image `python:3.7-slim-stretch`. I've just run your Dockerfile on my system and had absolutely no problem with it, exactly as you show it in your first code snippet.

Some suggestions that can be right or wrong, since I don't know what system you're running:

1. **Ensure you're getting the latest version of Docker image** `python:3.7-slim-stretch`. If you downloaded it over a month ago, chances are you don't have the latest version (as of the time of writing, said image was modified a month ago, which I checked [here](https://hub.docker.com/layers/python/library/python/3.7-slim-stretch/images/sha256-04f59867f40b86b819776cf47df3c2e5bec95953595bc02b9a3d8e63456593b6?context=explore)).

   For this, just run:

   `docker pull python:3.7-slim-stretch`

   And, to be on the safe side, you can also clear Docker build cache with:

   `docker builder prune -a`

​

2. **Update Docker** (if you can and won't brake compatibility with some other stuff of your workflow). How to do this will vary from system to system and preferred installation method. This is a big stretch but your version could have some rogue bug that needs no be taken care of.

​

3. **Check your processor arch**, since different architectures get different packages, so the fact that I was able to run your Dockerfile could mean nothing to you if you're, for example, on `arm` while I'm on `i386` (which I am). Dependencies also vary from arch to arch, so that could be an issue to look into. Checking the exact package name and version installed when you were able to install `openjdk-8-jdk` will surely help identify all its dependencies with a quick Google search and compare them with the dependencies of the package on the default repo.

Without having more info about your system and some debugging on the container that's created on your end, I can't really be more precise, so I hope this helps at least a bit.

​

Edit so the community's bot doesn't complaint: The OP wanted to know why the need existed to do something that shouldn't be required and I replied saying that it actually isn't required and gave 3 reasons why that could be the case. Basically, I can only assume a couple of things here without having more info about the OP's system, but it seems that the OP needed to add extra repos due to their processor's arch (again, a long shot, can't confirm without more info on the test case).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).